# Rendering multiple lists in jQuery UI Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to build website search, that covers multiple objects/models and I wanted to use jQuery Autocomplete to dynamically show the data.
The problem is, I want to pass three json lists instead of one, and display three lists (`<ul></ul>`), and not one. I did that by passing a dict containing json list as `source`, but I have no idea how to then cover each dict entry separately.
I figure I have to use `_renderMenu` and `_renderItem`, but I can't figure out how.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT

I can manipulate data however I want; for now I have:

```
{"ingredients": "[]",
 "products": "[]",
 "news": "[{"id": 7, "value": "Test revisionjjjj", "label": "Test revisionjjjj"}]"}
```

And I want to have it as something like:

```
<li class="ingredients"></li>
<li class="products"></li>
<li class="news">
    <ul ...>Test revisionjjjj</ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Write how looks your json data and how you want to display it

Comment: Why are you want to generate 3 separate lists on autocomplete suggestion box? Why you don't merge this list and use https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories

Comment: @suvroc because I need separate `ul`s to style it properly; is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

According to jQuery examples you should do something like this:

```
$.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _create: function() {
        this._super();
        this.widget().menu( "option", "items", "> :not(.ui-autocomplete-category)" );
    },
    _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
        var that = this;
        $.each(items, function(key, value) {
            ul.append( "<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + key + "</li>" );
            $.each( items, function( index, item ) {            
                var li = that._renderItemData( ul, item );
            }); 
        }
    }
});
```

I don't test it. It is only an idea.

Comment: I tried to extend this to my need, but unsuccessfully.

Comment: So what is your need different than this supported in my code?